# Java getConstructor() method

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {
String name;
public Test()
{
System.out.println("In Construtor");
}
public Test(String name)
{
this.name=name;
System.out.println("In Construtor paramitarized-----"+name);
}

public int q() {
    System.out.println("working");
    return 1;

}
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Class c=Class.forName("Test");
    Test t=(Test)c.newInstance();
    t.q();
    Constructor cons[]=c.getConstructors();
    for(Constructor ci:cons)
    ci.newInstance();
    Constructor<?> pcon=c.getConstructor(String.class);
    pcon.newInstance();
    System.out.println(Test.class.getName());
    }
}
```

I was just trying grasp the concepts of Class and ClassLoader Classes.
Now for this line `Constructor<?> pcon=c.getConstructor(String.class);` its showing that IllegalArgumentException: why?

Thank you Jon Skeet :) I changed my code with this and its working

```
Class c=Class.forName("Test");
        Test t=(Test)c.newInstance();
        t.q();


        Constructor<?> pcon=c.getConstructor(String.class);
        pcon.newInstance("arijit");
        System.out.println(Test.class.getName());
```

But When I am compiling with -Xlint ,its giving below mentioned warning:
Uncheck call getConstructor(java.lang.Class....) as a member of raw type java.lang.Class

What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed it. That's not the statement which is throwing an exception - this is:

```
ci.newInstance();
```

You're trying to call that for *both* constructors (due to the `for` loop) - so it'll be fine when it calls the parameterless constructor, but not when it calls the one with a `String` parameter. You'd have to change that call to pass in the right number of arguments depending on which constructor `ci` refers to at the time.

You have the same problem later:

```
pcon.newInstance();
```

This time you *know* there's a `String` parameter (you've just asked for a constructor with a string parameter) so you *absolutely know* that you should provide a `String` argument, e.g.

```
pcon.newInstance("foo");
```

Additionally, you should try to work out why you thought it was the `getConstructor()` call which was failing. The exception should have given you a stack trace with the right line on it... it's important to be able to diagnose problems accurately, so it's worth looking at what went wrong this time.

Comment: The problem is that he's calling `ci.newInstace()` with _every_ constructor.

Comment: @TedHopp: Indeed. Right statement, right reason - just missed the fact that it might already have worked once before the failure :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed my code like this and its working now.

Class c=Class.forName("Test");
  Test t=(Test)c.newInstance();
  t.q();
  
  
  Constructor<?> pcon=c.getConstructor(String.class);
  pcon.newInstance("arijit");
  System.out.println(Test.class.getName());

Comment: @Jon Skeet But When I am compiling with -Xlint ,its giving below mentioned warning: Uncheck call getConstructor(java.lang.Class....) as a member of raw type java.lang.Class

What does this mean?

Comment: Your `c` variable is just of type `Class`, which is a raw type. Use `Class<?>` and I suspect the error will go away.

Comment: @JonSkeet **"Additionally, you should try to work out why you thought it was the getConstructor() call which was failing. The exception should have given you a stack trace with the right line on it... it's important to be able to diagnose problems accurately, so it's worth looking at what went wrong this time."** Thank you for this suggestion.Next time I will do it.

Comment: Yes after changing it to Class<?> the problem disappeared. Thanks.